# Determining the value of the likelihood-ratio test statistic using a Binomial$(n, \theta)$

Tags: statistics

A coin is tossed 3 times and a single head is observed. Using a Binomial$(n, \theta)$ model for the number of heads observed in n tosses, what is the value of the likelihood-ratio test statistic for testing the hypothesis that the coin is fair, i.e testing $H_0 : \theta = 1/2$ against $H_1 : \theta \not = 1/2$ ?

---

My attempt:

Sources tell me that the Likelihood ratio for an unbiased coin test is given by $$  {\mathrm{L}(\theta = 1/2 ; x_1,x_2...x_n)} \over max[\mathrm{L}(\theta ;x_1,x_2...x_n)] $$

Where $max[\mathrm{L}(\theta ;x_1,x_2...x_n)] = \theta_{MLE}$

$n$ = number of tosses, in this case; $3$

Starting with the numerator; $$ \mathrm{L}(\theta = 1/2 \ ; \ x_1,x_2,x_3) = \mathrm{L}(\theta = 1/2 \ ;x_1)\mathrm{L}(\theta = 1/2 \ ;x_2)\mathrm{L}(\theta = 1/2; x_3)    $$
$$ \prod_{i=1}^3 \mathrm{L}(\theta;x_i) =   \prod_{i=1}^3 f(x_i;\theta) \quad (*) $$

(*) This is true because the sample is i.i.d. yes?

The probability function is  $$ {n \choose x}\theta^x(1-\theta)^{n-x} $$
 My understanding is that since there are 3 tosses, and only one heads appears, we have 3 terms to multiply, two in which $x=0$ and one where $x=1$ ; the $0$ and $1$ signifying the tails and the heads respectively .
Now I'm assuming that the order which this heads appeared doesn't matter. 
. Taking $\theta = 1/2$ , we get; $$ {3 \choose 1}(1/2)^1(1/2)^{2}{3 \choose 0}(1/2)^0(1/2)^{3}{3 \choose 0}(1/2)^0(1/2)^{3} = 18/64 $$

Now the denominator is where I think I'm going wrong.
The MLE of $\theta$ will just be $$ \frac{d \ell(\theta)}{d\theta} = 0 $$ and solve for $\theta$.

Given that $$ln(\mathrm{L}) = ln{n \choose x} + xln(\theta) + (n-x)ln(1- \theta)$$

and $$ \ell(\theta) = ln(\mathrm{L}) = ln{\prod_{i=1}^3 \mathrm{L}(\theta;x_i)} = \sum_{i=1}^3 ln\mathrm{L}(\theta;x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^3\ell(\theta;x_i) $$

$$ \ell(\theta) = ln{3 \choose 1} + ln(\theta) + (2)ln(1- \theta) + 2[ln{3 \choose 0} + 0ln(\theta) + (3)ln(1- \theta)]$$

which reduced to $$ \ell(\theta)=ln{3 \choose 1} + ln(\theta) + 8ln(1- \theta) $$

Taking the derivative of this w.r.t $\theta$ and solving for $\theta$, I got $$(\theta_{MLE}) = 1/7$$

When I sub the two values into my original equation, I got $${\frac{18}{64}} \over \frac{1}{7} $$
The 5 options I have for answers are $ 0, \frac{1}{32}, \frac{27}{32}, \frac{32}{27}, none \ of \ the \ above $

I'm not confident enough with my workings as there is a lot of room for errors in a problem like this, so can anyone tell me if I've gone wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model for the number of heads observed in $n$ trials is binomial, but the model for whether a single trial results in a head is Bernoulli.  What you've done in your calculation of the numerator is not correct, because once you've been told that the sample contains $x = 1$ head in $n = 3$ tosses, the likelihood is given by a **single** binomial experiment, not three:  $$\mathcal L(\theta = 1/2 \mid x = 1) = \Pr[X = 1 \mid \theta = 1/2] = \binom{3}{1} (1/2)^1 (1 - 1/2)^{3-1} = \frac{3}{8}.$$  You could write the same likelihood using the Bernoulli model:  $$\mathcal L(\theta = 1/2 \mid x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1) = \Pr[(X_1, X_2, X_3) = (1,0,0) \mid \theta = 1/2] + \Pr[(X_1, X_2, X_3) = (0,1,0) \mid \theta = 1/2] + \Pr[(X_1, X_2, X_3) = (0,0,1) \mid \theta = 1/2] = \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8}$$ but this is unnecessary.  What you've written down is a likelihood for three binomial experiments each with $n = 3$, one of which has $X = 1$ and the others $X = 0$.

To calculate the MLE of the binomial success parameter, it suffices to write $$\mathcal L(\theta \mid x) \propto \Pr[X = x \mid \theta] \propto \theta^x (1 - \theta)^{n-x},$$ hence $$\ell (\theta \mid x) = x \log \theta + (n-x) \log (1-\theta), \\ \frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \theta} = \frac{x}{\theta} - \frac{n-x}{1-\theta},$$ hence the likelihood is maximized for some $\theta$ satisfying $\partial \ell/\partial \theta = 0$ provided $x \ne 0$ or $x \ne n$.  That is to say, we solve $x/\theta = (n-x)/(1-\theta)$, or $\theta = x/n$.  It follows that the sample proportion of successes is the MLE:  $$\hat \theta = \frac{x}{n}$$ and in your case, the denominator of the LRT statistic is simply $1/3$.